# SQL server management studio : Cannot find one or more component please reinstall the application

Tags: sql-server

I had visual studio 2010 on my VM and I Uninstalled it by visual studio 2010 uninstall utility which I downloaded from here :
https://aka.ms/vs2010uninstall
it also uninstalled visual studio 2010 shell...
Then I Installed Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. After that, I can't open sql server management studio 2012. It gives me this error :
Cannot find one or more component please reinstall the application.
also when I try to repair it, it gives me this error:

### TITLE: SQL Server Setup failure.

SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:

The required MSI package 'c:\6b55b72929daeb5953cfca72\1033_ENU_LP\redist\VisualStudioShell\VSIntSetup\vs_setup.msi' doesn't exist.

Error code 0x858C0038.

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&EvtType=0xFDC38F1F%25400xE62C46B1%25401420%254056

what should I do?!

Comment: Have you tried doing what it says; reinstalling it? have you tried SSMS 2017/2018 instead?

Comment: Repair and Reinstall aren't the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL server management is sharing a lot of components with visual studio, in order to use it on the same machine the painless and best option is to keep them aligned as much as possible. 
Except in case you are going to connect to a newer (Azure) version of SQL-SERVER you can easily solve the situation by uninstalling the current version of SQL Server Management and installing MS-SQL Server Management 2016. 
Likely also installing even a newer version will not gave issues, but using an older one will be a source of troubles and also a no-sense since the Management Studio is backward compatible with older SQL Server versions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Start regedit.exe
2. Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio
3. Delete 11.0_Config
4. Restart ssms.exe